# Scrolling adding a hash to url + adding class when id in window

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider

I was quite happy with my jQuery-solution until I noticed that scrolling is not working properly on chrome, on some cell phones and tablets. That is, scrolling is jumpy and the hashes occur in an ambiguous and irritating way. I am using wordpress + Slider Revolution 6.

So these are my functions:

1. when an id is in the viewport, its button gets a class (underline).
2. when an id is in the viewport, the url gets extended with the id's name (#id)
3. additionally, not shown here and part of the Slider Revolution 6, I use "menu-link+scroll to id"

So, the code below looks comprehensible and simple to me. But I cannot figure out why chrome on some phones and tablets makes the above mentioned problems. I have tried to clear caches everywhere.

```
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();
    
        var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();
    
        return (docViewBottom >= elemTop && docViewTop <= elemBottom);
    }
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  element = jQuery('#first');
  if (isScrolledIntoView(element) === true) {
    jQuery('#first-btn').addClass('underline');
     history.replaceState(null,null,'#first');//or pushState?
  } else {
    jQuery('#first-btn').removeClass('underline');
  }
  
  element = jQuery('#second');
  if (isScrolledIntoView(element) === true) {
    jQuery('#second-btn').addClass('underline');
     history.replaceState(null,null,'#second');//or pushState?
  } else {
    jQuery('#second-btn').removeClass('underline');
  }
});
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skt

Comment: When you say "scrolling is not working properly", what do you mean exactly? i.e. is the hash and/or class not getting added as expected, or if the actual scrolling action not working?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Sorry if I wasn't clear. The scroll is jumpy, and the hash adding is often delayed or not happening. That is, only on chrome on certain phones.

Comment: Ok, I get it! You should update your question with this info too because some people might miss it in the comments. You have multiple `jQuery(window).scroll(function() {` in your code - I'm not sure is this is for some specific reason, but could you just use one around all your code for scrolling, otherwise you have multiple functions running when scrolling which could be reason its jumpy on some OSs. It should help but I won't add it as an answer yet in case you need more help than just that. Give it a go and let me know how it goes!

Comment: oh yes, I actually tried that too! I have changed above now. But the same devices are still jumpy on chrome. It is very strange.

Comment: Do you have many elements to keep track of when scrolling? I see you've added a `or PushState?` comment - did you try that? That would probably reduce the workload of the browser a bit too. My initial thoughts are that its trying to do so much that its slowing down the scrolling on Chrome on android so any reductions could help. But that's all I have, I'm afraid!

Comment: Yeah, you might be right. There can be some conflicts. I have taken out all other IDs as a test. But Wordpress in combination with Slider revolution create a really overcomplex code. This could be the problem rather than the above. 

 PushState is also jumpy. This is very strange. But now I guess I can live with it, given that it occurs on only some devices.